# Copy PostGIS raster between databases

Tags: raster, postgis, copy

I want to copy PostGIS rasters - table with columns(rid integer, rast raster) from one PostGIS database (version 2.5) into another db (3.2). In the target Postgis 3.2 DB I have the `postgis_raster` extention enabled. What is the best way to transfer the data, ideally multiple PostGIS rasters, layers (feature classes) and tables at the same time? I know about `pg_dump` to dump it into file, but I am looking for something more direct, ideally with GUI wizard.
My postgis rasters are arround 2GB in size in postgis db. I created them by importing data from TIFF files using `raster2pgsql`.

So far I tried:

- I tried copy and paste in ArcCatalog, doesn´t work because AG doesnt know the raster type in tables.
- I tried DBeaver export into database wizard, but I get `Java heap space` error even when I run DBEAVER with increased aloocated memory using `-vmargs -Xmx4096m` flag.

Any other suggestions how can I migrate multiple pg rasters, layers and tables into new database in one bulk data transfer?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use PostgreSQL [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) ?
With FDW you can open a remote (source) table from your target database and copy data with a simple SQL query : `CREATE TABLE local_table AS SELECT * FROM foreign_table`.

No GUI, but FDW is well documented (`CREATE SERVER -> CREATE USER MAPPING, -> CREATE FOREIGN TABLE or IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`)

I don't know if this is really efficient, but you don't have to handle large files.

Comment: thank you, I tried something similar using `dblink` and it worked too